# How to set snack bar's label color?

Tags: flutter

How can I set custom color for snackBar's label since it is defined as String?

```
  final snackBar = SnackBar(
    content: Text(_message),
    action: SnackBarAction(
      label: 'Close',
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could change the color of the `SnackBarAction` label using the `textColor` parameter. Please see below for a code sample showing how this could be done.

```
final snackBar = SnackBar(
  content: Text(_message),
  action: SnackBarAction(
    textColor: Colors.red,
    label: 'Close',
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
);
```

Alternatively, you could set the text color of all `SnackBarAction` labels using the global [`snackBarTheme`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/snackBarTheme.html) parameter of the application's `ThemeData`.

```
return MaterialApp(
  home: HomePage(),
  theme: ThemeData(
    snackBarTheme: SnackBarThemeData(
      actionTextColor: Colors.red,
    ),
  ),
);
```